# Is it possible to initialize a struct within a function in C without dynamic memory allocation such that it persists after the function returns?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am currently building a dynamic memory management class in C for a school project. As part of the initialization for my heap I want to initialize a Block struct into the free memory list. I cannot use dynamic memory allocation to do this (as it is against the rules). This design is entirely of my own creation, so my approach may just be flawed. Is it possible to do? Code below will clarify exactly what I am trying to do. Based on my understanding of how C handles variables, the memory location for newBlock will be up for grabs as soon as the function ends which could lead to issues later if it is overwritten.

```
int mm_init()
{
    // Initialize memory. Don't worry about this.
    mem_init();

    // Initialize the heap.
    // Also don't worry about this.
    list_init(heap.freeBlocks);
    list_init(heap.allocatedBlocks);

    // Here is where the question applies.
    Block newBlock = //initialize the block.

    // freeBlocks is a pointer to a list struct.
    list_insert(heap.freeBlocks, &newBlock);

    // Don't worry about this either.
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Make it global / static...

Comment: This probably makes me sound like an idiot, but what do you mean? I am a little shaky on what the term static means in C as it seems to vary from language to language.

Comment: As @EugeneSh. said, make it global, if you need use it in all program, it is the best way

Comment: A `static struct` defined inside a function retains its value from one call to the next. But both global and local static variables are usually a poor solution.

Comment: You can also return a struct.

Comment: @WeatherVane If one is designing a stateful API, global variables are just fine.

Comment: @WeatherVane if you declare and define a struct inside a function and make it `extern`... It can be used in other functions, right?

Comment: @JuMoGar the point of defining a static variable inside a function is that it is not visible externally.

Comment: @KennethNagies A static declaration inside a function (in your case it would probably mean `static Block newblock;`) effectively means the declared variable is a non-extern global but one that can only be directly looked up from its parent function. A static declaration outside a function may be directly used from any function that follows but not from other translation units. Nonstatic globals, static globals and static locals all have "static" storage duration, which means the storage for them is allocated in one fell swoop when the program is loaded and lasts as long as the process does.

Comment: If the idea is that you're implementing dynamic memory allocation yourself, without using the dynamic memory allocation routines from the standard library, then wouldn't you just get memory pages as needed directly from the operating system, using system calls, and use those to fill allocation requests and hold bookkeeping information?

Comment: `Block newBlock = //initialize the block.`  Is the data determinable at compile time or does determined early at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the variable has what's called *static storage duration*.

Static storage duration means that the object will be allocated in one fell swoop along with other objects with static storage duration at program start and will never be deallocated as long as the program lives.

There are 3 ways to give a C object the static storage duration.

1. Make it global -- this will make it accessible from other translation units as well

   ```
   Block newBlock;

   int mm_init() {
       /* ... */ 
   }
   ```
2. Make it global and mark it `static` -- this will make the identifier only accessible from the current translation unit

   ```
   static Block newBlock;

   int mm_init() { 
       /* ... */
   }
   ```
3. Make it local and mark it `static` -- this will prevent the identifier from being accessible outside its enclosing function

   ```
   int mm_init() {
       static Block newBlock;

       /* ... */
   }
   ```